# Correct constness with pointer / object / template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, constants

I have a template class foo (essentially a matrix). The template parameter for foo can only be `int`, `float`, or `double`, i.e., not `const int`. The reason for this is that I have specialized operators for these, and it seems redundant to duplicate the operators for the const cases. I have two `get_data` functions, which return a pointer with appropriate constness. But I also wan't a `row` function that selects a single row and returns a `const foo`, such that the caller cannot modify the returned object.

My questions:

1) How can i make B const?

2) Should I make operator functions for e.g. foo ?

2) Should I make a reference_foo class?

```
template <class T>
class foo
{
    using uint8_t = unsigned char;

    int rows = 0;
    int cols = 0;    
    T * data = nullptr;
    bool reference = false;

public:
    foo() = default;
    //foo(const foo&) // this is not included here for simplicity
    //foo& operator=(const foo&) // this is not included here for simplicity

    foo(int r, int c) : rows(r), cols(c)
    {
        data = new T[rows * cols];
    }

    ~foo()
    {
        if (!reference)
        {
            delete[] data;
        }
    }

    T * get_data()
    {
        return data;
    }

    T const * get_data() const
    {
        return data;
    }

    const foo row(int r) const
    {
        foo t;
        t.rows = 1;
        t.cols = cols;
        t.reference = true;
//        t.data = get_data() + r * cols; // ERROR: invalid conversion from 'const uint8_t*' to 'uint8_t*'
        t.data = const_cast<T*>(get_data()) + r * cols; // Not pretty, but "ok" if the returned object is const
        return t;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    const foo<int> A(2, 1);
//    A.get_data()[0] = 1; // ERROR: assignment of read-only location, perfectly catched by compiler
    auto B = A.row(1);
    B.get_data()[0] = 1; // B is not const... overwritten...

    return 0;
}
```

The operator functions has been left out for simplicity.

Comment: I get this then error (if I use `const int` as template parameter and try using a operator): no match for 'operator+=' (operand types are 'foo<const int>' and 'foo<int>')

Comment: sry the link was wrong, I will look for a better one

Comment: I think that option #3, `const_foo`, is the cleanest option.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I like it, from a syntax point-of-view (it is similar to `const_iterator`), but then I would have to make a metric-ton of functions to handle the two class together.

Comment: Not necessarily, if you make `foo` inherit from `const_foo`, and implement all the `const` methods in `const_foo`, with the `protected` pointer, and the flag stored in `const_foo`, and by `using` all the const methods from `foo`. With most C++ library containers, `iterator` inherits from `const_iterator`.

Comment: do you want to propagate the foo's constness onto the view of data in the foo?

Comment: @RichardHodges Yes, I want B's data to be const since it is a reference to the const data in A.

Comment: @Jonas solution posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 kinds of constness here. Const data and const handle.

What we want to do is create sanity out of the four combinations:

- const handle, const data = const
- const handle, mutable data = const
- mutable handle, const data = const
- mutable handle, mutable data = mutable

Furthermore, marking a return value as const has no meaning. A return value is an r-value. It will be either copied or moved. This will not result in a const handle at the call site.

So we need to detect constness in 2 places in respect of `get_data()`. C++ does the first for us with a const overload. Then we must defer to another template which is evaluated in deduced context so we can use `std::enable_if`:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

// default getter - element != const element
template<class Element, typename = void>
struct data_getter
{
  using element_type = Element;
  using const_element_type = std::add_const_t<element_type>;

  // detect mutable container    
  element_type* operator()(element_type ** pp) const
  {
    return *pp;
  }

  // detect const container
  const_element_type* operator()(element_type * const * pp) const
  {
    return *pp;
  }


};

// specific specialisation for element == const element    
template<class Element>
struct data_getter<Element,
std::enable_if_t<
  std::is_same<Element, std::add_const_t<Element>>::value>>
{
  // in this case the container's constness is unimportant, so
  // we use const because it means only writing one method
  Element* operator()(Element *const* p) const
  {
    return *p;
  }
};

template <class T>
class foo
{
  public:
  using element = T;
  using const_element = std::add_const_t<element>;

    int rows = 0;
    int cols = 0;    
    element * data = nullptr;
    bool reference = false;

public:
    foo() = default;
    //foo(const foo&) // this is not included here for simplicity
    //foo& operator=(const foo&) // this is not included here for simplicity


    foo(int r, int c) : rows(r), cols(c)
    {
        data = new element[rows * cols];
    }

    ~foo()
    {
        if (!reference)
        {
            delete[] data;
        }
    }

    decltype(auto) get_data()
    {
      // defer to getter
      return data_getter<element>()(&data);
    }

    decltype(auto) get_data() const
    {
      // defer to getter
      return data_getter<const_element>()(&data);
    }

    // this will return a mutable container of const data    
    foo<const_element> row(int r) const
    {
        foo<const_element> t;
        t.rows = 1;
        t.cols = cols;
        t.reference = true;
        t.data = get_data() + r * cols;
        return t;
    }
};

int main() 
{
    foo<int> A(2, 1);
    A.get_data()[0] = 1;

  auto AC = A.row(0);
  auto x = AC.get_data()[0];   // fine

//  AC.get_data()[0] = 1; // assignment of read-only location

    return 0;
}
```